# What is RealFloat type in Haskell used for?

Tags: haskell, typeclass

In the **Learn You A Haskell** book, there is an example about calculating your BMI.

```
bmiTell :: (RealFloat a) => a -> a -> String
bmiTell weight height
    | bmi <= skinny = "You're underweight, you emo, you!"
    | bmi <= normal = "You're supposedly normal. Pffft, I bet you're ugly!"
    | bmi <= fat    = "You're fat! Lose some weight, fatty!"
    | otherwise     = "You're a whale, congratulations!"
    where bmi = weight / height ^ 2
          (skinny, normal, fat) = (18.5, 25.0, 30.0)
```

When I tried to do this example by myself, I used `(Num a) => a -> a -> String` as the type signature for the method. However that threw the following error:

```
Could not deduce (Ord a) arising from a use of ‘<=’
    from the context (Num a)
      bound by the type signature for
                 bmiTell :: Num a => a -> a -> String
      at scratch.hs:96:12-38
    Possible fix:
      add (Ord a) to the context of
        the type signature for bmiTell :: Num a => a -> a -> String
```

I was not able to resolve the error just using the `Num` and `Ord` typeclasses. Why do I need to use `RealFloat` typeclass to make this piece of code work? What is so special about `RealFloat` that is not covered by `Num`?

Comment: Try leaving off the type signature to see what GHC deduces it to be.  It should be able to correctly identify all necessary constraints.  Many of the operators used in this function definition are from typeclasses, so you have to have your desired type implementing those type classes to gain access to them.

Comment: @bheklilr Oh.. wow, I see. Thank you for your comment. I did try it. GHC gave me back `bmiTell :: (Fractional a, Ord a) => a -> a -> [Char]` as the type signature, which obviously works when I type it in my code : ). It makes a little bit more sense. I am still confused about why `bmiTell :: (Num a, Ord a) => a -> a -> [Char]` wont work. Is it because the `Num` typeclass contains complex numbers also? And I guess complex numbers can NOT be ordered?

Comment: @user2407334 `Num` is *too* general, and thus includes types like `Int` for which `/` is not defined.

Comment: @user2407334 A `(Num a, Ord a)` constraint would just say that any type which happens to be an instance of both `Num` and `Ord` would be acceptable. The fact that `Complex Double` is a `Num` but not an `Ord`, or, for that matter, the fact that `Bool` is an `Ord` but not a `Num`, doesn't affect that.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

While `Num` is not enough, `RealFloat` is indeed excessive for this example. `Fractional`, which is necessary for `(/)`, is good enough:

```
GHCi> :t (/)
(/) :: Fractional a => a -> a -> a
```

An appropriate signature, then, would be:

```
bmiTell :: (Fractional a, Ord a) => a -> a -> String
```

[`RealFloat`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:RealFloat) is a class for floating point types, while [`Fractional`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:Fractional) covers everything that supports real division. `Double` is a `RealFloat` (and also a `Fractional`, as that is a superclass of `RealFloat`). The `Ratio` type for rational numbers, available from [`Data.Ratio`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Data-Ratio.html), is an example of a `Fractional` that isn't a `RealFloat`.

See also: [Ben's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41130559/2751851), which considers why the book might have used `RealFloat` rather than the arguably simpler alternative shown here.

Comment: How can `Fractional` be enough when it doesn't provide `<=`? Haskell newbie here.

Comment: @VictorZamanian Indeed; `<=` is provided by [`Ord`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:Ord), which also constrains `a` in the  `bmiTell` signature I have suggested here.

Comment: Oh right, you have two typeclasses there, duh. Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

In addition to `/` as noted in duplode's answer, you use non-integer literals like `18.5`. Those can't be used as every `Num` type (what would `18.5 :: Integer` be, for example?), so you can't promise that your function can handle any `Num` type the caller likes.

I suspect the book uses `RealFloat` simply because it also implies `Ord` (via `RealFrac` and `Real`), so that it was only necessary to write a single constraint. Multiple constraints might have made the example look more complex and intimidating, with a feature that isn't the point of the exercise.

Comment: Good call on the likely rationale by the book author. I'm not sure if it pays off (what is more costly: introducing a mildly esoteric class instead of a more obvious one, or making a side remark about a feature which is not being focused?), but it can be argued either way.